# Canvas: Continue lineTo path but with x fixed

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/5xcbbqtL/5/

I am plotting two lines with x,y points. Then I am taking the radians from the start and end of the second line.

When I then try and use the radians to extrapolate the second line so that it is longer I fail to create a straight line as I want to move to a fixed x position

where

```
var radian=Math.atan2(endY-startY,endX-startX);
var y=endY+100*Math.sin(radian);

pen.lineTo(200,y);  // < problem
```

moving to a fixed position is like adding a skewing effect it seems. How do I correctly carry on the line but to stop at 'x' 200

Comment: did you try growing the height of you canvas ? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the slope-intercept formula to extend your line to a desired X:

```
function extendToX(desiredX,x0,y0,x1,y1){
    var m=(y0-y1)/(x0-x1);
    var b=y1-(m*x1);
    return(m*desiredX+b);
}
```

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/c2ba9d9y/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var x0=25;
    var y0=50;
    var x1=150;
    var y1=150;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x0,y0);
    ctx.lineTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.strokeStyle='blue';
    ctx.stroke();

    var newY=extendToX(200,x0,y0,x1,y1);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.lineTo(200,newY);
    ctx.strokeStyle='red';
    ctx.stroke();

    function extendToX(desiredX,x0,y0,x1,y1){
        var m=(y0-y1)/(x0-x1);
        var b=y1-(m*x1);
        return(m*desiredX+b);
    }


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Use slope-intercept formula to extend line</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```